# How to parse data from .TX0 file into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I'm trying to basically convert a .TX0 file from a  chromatogram file. the file is just a bunch of results including retention times etc... I want to eventually pick certain pieces of data from multiple files and do some analysis. So far I have:

```
filename = 'filepath'
f = open(filename, 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
print lines
```

my output is:

```
Out[29]: 
[....................................................



 '"condensate analysis (HP4890 Optic - FID)"\n',
 '"Peak","Component","Time","Area","Height","BL"\n',
 '"#","Name","[min]","[uV*sec]","[uV]",""\n',
 '------,------,------,------,------,------\n',


'1,"Methane",0.689,5187666.22,994337.57,*BB\n',
 '2,"Ethane",1.061,1453339.93,729285.09,*BB\n',
 '3,"Propane",1.715,193334.09,63398.74,*BB\n',
 '4,"i-Butane",2.792,157630.92,29233.56,*BV\n',
 '5,"n-Butane",3.240,98943.96,15822.72,*VB\n',
 '"","","",------,------,""\n',
 '"","","",7090915.11,1.83e+06,""\n',
 '"Missing Component Report"\n',
 '"Component","Expected Retention (Calibration File)"\n',
 '------,------\n',
 '"All components were found"\n',
 '"Report stored in ASCII file :","...
 "\n'.......................]
```

Now, the problem i'm having. I can't get this output into a structured dataframe using pandas... =/ I've tried and it just gives me two columns...

```
pd.DataFrame(filename)

out:

Out[26]: 
                                                    0
0   "=============================================...
1   "Software Version:",6.3.2.0646,"Date:","08/06/...
2             "Reprocess Number:","vma2: ......................
.......................
10                                               ""\n
11                                               ""\n
12       "condensate analysis (HP4890 Optic - FID)"\n
13   "Peak","Component","Time","Area","Height","BL"\n
14          "#","Name","[min]","[uV*sec]","[uV]",""\n
15        ------,------,------,------,------,------\n
16       1,"Methane",0.689,5187666.22,994337.57,*BB\n
17        2,"Ethane",1.061,1453339.93,729285.09,*BB\n
18         3,"Propane",1.715,193334.09,63398.74,*BB\n
19        4,"i-Butane",2.792,157630.92,29233.56,*BV\n
20         5,"n-Butane",3.240,98943.96,15822.72,*VB\n
21                        "","","",------,------,""\n
22                  "","","",7090915.11,1.83e+06,""\n
23                       "Missing Component Report"\n
24  "Component","Expected Retention (Calibration F...
25                                    ------,------\n
26                      "All components were found"\n
27  "Report stored in ASCII file :","C:\Shared Fol...
```

Comment: You should get rid of the annotation lines. Try using regular expressions to achieve this. However, could you please provide more information about the file format resp. the lines before the and after the 'data block'?

Comment: This seems to be a very uncommon file format. You may have to write a parser that reads line by line and extracts the required information yourself.